# SQL Get most recent date after filtering by date

Tags: sql-server, date

I have two tables that have dates that needs to be considered in my SQL.

- Tables (t1) has a date that records any changes to an entity (something like a modified date).
- Table (t2) has a date that records when records in t2 is created.

I need to identify what was the state of the data in t1 when t2 record was created. So I understand that the modified date must be before the record was created. Which I already did. But then it needs to be the last modification that was made before the record in t2 was created.

How do I accomplish this? I created a fiddle here:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3eb3c/1)

**UPDATE:** I was able to get an answer that is 90% workable. The only issue I have now is if the there is an exact match in the dates

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3eb3c/19)

For the Charles Xavier record the data comes back as 'at' where it should be 't1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the minor bug that happened was the outer apply should be ordered by the date if it needed the most recent

```
SELECT t1.StaffName, t1.DateAppointed, t2.DateSet, t2.PName
FROM Staff t1
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 m.DateSet, m.PName
  FROM MPHist m
  WHERE t1.DateAppointed >= m.DateSet AND m.PvpId = t1.PvpId
  ORDER BY m.DateSet
) t2
```

Needed to post the SQL as SQLFiddle was bugging out when attempting to update the fiddle or even create a new one